# Should I have a variable as random?

Tags: random-variable, model

I have put individual ID as a random variable in my model, but some individuals only have 1 record and others have 19 records.

Does this mean that individual ID shouldn't be a random variable?

Here's the context: 
I have birds visiting a feeder and want to know if the length of a visit is determined by species (3 options), site (3 options), and indiviudal ID.

The model I'm running currently is

lenght ~ species + site + (1|id)

Comment: No, it does not mean that.

Comment: Unless you tell us more about what is your data and what are you trying to achieve, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Tim, sorry! I'll add some context.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you for your response

Comment: Thanks, I think it is already answered in here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242821/how-will-random-effects-with-only-1-observation-affect-a-generalized-linear-mixe is it?

Comment: Thanks @Tim for the help!